# How can I setup validation to replace before it saves?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When a user inputs `<h1>John` to the text field and saves, I want it to be saved as `&gt;h1&lt;John` instead.

To make it possible, how can I code in my model?

It's User model's `name` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a callback:

```
class YourModel
  before_save :sanitize_name

  private

    def sanitize_name
      self.name = CGI::escapeHTML(name)
    end
end
```